whay proxychains is not working on ubuntu
guys where is the issue i do like the tutorial but my location do not change

i tried to do everything in tutorial but not working
this is the tutorial i used
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Csghy8IrAaQ

i tried all possible ways it also didn't work for me on Ubuntu so i decided to switch to Kali Linux worked like a charm
